# OpenGL ES texture partially removing

Tags: ios, opengl-es

Is there any way to remove a part of texture by using opengles for ios? for example i have a rectangle and want to destroy part of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need this: [How to manipulate texture content on the fly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887636/how-to-manipulate-texture-content-on-the-fly/10702468#10702468)

Either create an empty texture and render a small quad using this empty texture on top of the FBO for your texture or use the glTexSubImage2D, which is easier for this simple purpose.